# Record the largest series for each id in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to to keep one record that has the largest series for each id. So for each id I need one row. I think I need something like

```
df_new = df.groupby('id')['series'].nlargest(1)
```

, but that's definitely wrong.

That's how my dataset looks:

```
id  series s1 s2 s3
1   2      4  9  1
1   8      6  2  2
1   3      9  1  3
2   9      4  1  5
2   2      2  5  5
2   5      1  7  8
3   6      7  2  3
3   2      4  4  1
3   1      3  9  9
```

This should be the result:

```
id  series s1 s2 s3
1   8      6  2  2
2   9      4  1  5
3   6      7  2  3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and aggregate [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(by="series", ascending=False).groupby("id", as_index=False).first()
print (df)
   id  series  s1  s2  s3
0   1       8   6   2   2
1   2       9   4   1   5
2   3       6   7   2   3
```

Answer (score 6):

IIUC you want to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on 'id' column and get the index label where the 'Series' value is the largest using [`idxmax()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and use this to index back in the orig df:

```
In [91]:
df.loc[df.groupby('id')['series'].idxmax()]

Out[91]:
   id  series  s1  s2  s3
1   1       8   6   2   2
3   2       9   4   1   5
6   3       6   7   2   3
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one NumPy based solution -

```
def grouby_max(df):
    arr = df[['id','series']].values
    n = arr.shape[0]-1
    idx = (arr[:,0]*(arr[:,1].max()+1) + arr[:,1]).argsort()
    sidx = np.append(np.nonzero(arr[idx[1:],0] > arr[idx[:-1],0])[0],n)
    return df.iloc[idx[sidx]]
```

Runtime test -

```
In [201]: # Setup input
     ...: N = 100 # Number of groups
     ...: data = np.random.randint(11,999999,(10000,5))
     ...: data[:,0] = np.sort(np.random.randint(1,N+1,(data.shape[0])))
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[['id','series','s1','s2','s3']])
     ...: 

In [202]: %timeit df.loc[df.groupby('id')['series'].idxmax()]
100 loops, best of 3: 15.8 ms per loop #@EdChum's soln

In [203]: %timeit df.sort_values(by="series", ascending=False).groupby("id", as_index=False).first()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.52 ms per loop #@jezrael's soln

In [204]: %timeit grouby_max(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 1.96 ms per loop
```